# Blogger API Retrieve usage limit

Tags: blogger

I am using Google's blogger API post blog entries automatically.
The limit is 50, but when exceed the limit it just throws error.

Is there any way to retrieve usage out of 50 so I can stop process before it fails?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to create a variable, then simply increment it with each request. The code would be like this:

```
if (numberOfSentRequests<=50) {
    sendBloggerRequest();
}
```

You could also use a try/catch block. I don't think the Blogger API would have a function to keep track of the number of requests.